# Uninstall VSTO Outlook Add-In while Outlook remains open

Tags: outlook, vsto, clickonce, uninstallation

I have created my VSTO Add-In installer using "ClickOnce". I am using "VSTOInstaller.exe" to install and uninstall using PowerShell script. The uninstallation works fine when the Outlook is not running. However, when it is running, even though uninstall does not show any error, it does not uninstall the add-in. None of the relevant registry entries are deleted. Is there any "force" option to uninstall it? How can it be done when Outlook is up and running?

Answer (score 0):

I think forcefully closing outlook will not solve your problem as maybe user is working on some mails and if you close it forcefully user will loss unsaved mails.

However, if you still want to do it.
you can create a new form along with your project
and use this code

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Length > 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK")[0];
                proc.Kill();
                
            }
```

Otherwise you can put a popup to tell user to close the outlook from its end so that user can save its already opened work before closing outlook.